# Why do co-ops dominate in certain markets rather than more-conventional enterprises?

Tags: markets, agriculture, cooperative-game-theory

Why do co-ops dominate in certain markets rather than more-conventional enterprises?

For example, the US dairy processing market seems to be dominated co-ops like Land'O Lakes and Dairy Farmers of America, while meat processing (a nominally-similar market) is dominated by multinational public companies.

Are there significant barriers to entry for co-ops trying to move into markets already dominated by conventional enterprises?  Or vice versa, are there barriers to entry for conventional enterprises wanting to enter markets controlled by co-ops?  If barriers to entry are overcome, does either form of enterprise have an ongoing competitive advantage?

Comment: [Here](http://www.iuf.org/sites/cms.iuf.org/files/USA%20Dairy%20Industry.pdf) is some additionial reading on the subject for would be answerers.